# how to change python interpreter used by jedi-vim

Tags: linux, vimscript-python, plugin-jedi-vim

I have `Anaconda` (including python3.5.2), `VIM` (7.4) and `Jedi-VIM` installed on my system. There was also a `python` installed on the linux system by default.

The autocompletion is working on base packages, at least. But for packages like `numpy` (which was included in `Anaconda`) the completion is not working.

By using the following command in `VIM`:

```
:py3 import sys; print(sys.path)

['/usr/lib/python35.zip', 
'/usr/lib/python3.5', 
'/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
'/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', 
'_vim_path_']
```

This indicates to me that the `Anaconda-python` interpreter and the packages are never been used by `jedi-vim`.

```
$which python
/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python
```

How can I get jedi-vim to use also the path of anaconda python for getting package autocompletion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself by providing `jedi-vim` with the location of the packages in my `anaconda` folder using the `$PYTHONPATH` variable as follows:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Thanks to all!

Or Add following line in ~/.bash_profile

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: Thanks! Adding `export PYTHONPATH="/home/user-name/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages":$PYTHONPATH` to my `~/.zshrc` got jedi-vim to work correctly with anaconda.

Comment: You should not do that. That might lead to a SEGFAULT. It's dangerous.

Comment: @DaveHalter When you said it might lead to a SEGFAULT, were you referring to what was proposed in the answer or what was proposed in the previous comment? Also, do you know _why_ a SEGFAULT might occur?

Comment: @JackKinsella Python versions need to match, otherwise when compiled modules get imported you load different versions. However I have updated my answer below. There are now environments in Jedi, which make this all easily possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  The `:python` and `:python3` commands always use the compiled-in interpreters.  If you have a recent version of Vim with `python` and / or `python3` loaded dynamically (see `:h python-dynamic`) you can use `pythondll` and `pythonthreedll` to load different interpreters, but replacing CPython by Anaconda is IMO asking for segfaults (provided that Vim accepts it at all, that is).

Answer (score 3):

## 2018+ Jedi Versions

You can just use `:let jedi#force_py_version=3.8` if you want to switch to the latest Python version, for example. Unfortunately there is no environment listing in jedi-vim, yet. We need to build that (it is available in Jedi, though).

---

## Old Answer

Basically the only thing you can do currently is to compile VIM with Python 3.5 support. That's probably a stupid idea, but it works.

Otherwise there will be support for cross Python versions, with https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/385.

Note that it might be possible to modify the Python PATH, but that might lead to a SEGFAULT and to other unwanted behavior, because you're basically allowing Jedi to run binary code from another Python version (Yes it actually happens).

Answer (score 1):

You could compile vim with anaconda:
I did `./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/config/`, I remember that I did similar tests afterwards and `:py import sys; print sys.path` was giving me correct results.

Based on the [web search](http://www.xorpd.net/blog/vim_python3_install.html) you could perhaps do something like this (ex. for 3.4):

`./configure --enable-python3interp --with-features=huge --with-python3-config-dir=~/anaconda/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 1):

David has a valid point about intermingling Vim with different flavors of Python and if hard coding `PYTHONPATH` to Anaconda Python in `.profile`/`.bashrc` really does lead to SEG 11 could one use a shell alias.

```
alias vim3='PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/Anaonda/.../site-packages vim'
```

Perhaps this work-around will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 32bit vim for compatibility with other extensions, but the 64 bit python is first on my PATH for other reasons.  Hence I [installed the 32 bit python using conda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17963884/1519199) via:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda create -n py27_32bit python=2.7
activate py27_32bit
pip install jedi
deactivate
```

and added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
if has('win32')&& isdirectory('C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/envs/py27_32bit/')
    let $PATH = 'C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/envs/py27_32bit/;
                \C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/envs/py27_32bit/lib/;' . $PATH
    let $PYTHONPATH = 'C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/envs/py27_32bit/;
                \C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/envs/py27_32bit/DLLs/;
                \:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/envs/py27_32bit/lib/;' 
endif
```

where `C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2` is the result of calling `conda info --base`

Answer (score 1):

*The following approach was not tested with Anaconda, but it fixed the issues for me when working with virtualenvwrapper*

**The [vim-virtualenv](https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv) plugin changes the executable and modifies `sys.path` and the `$PATH` environment.**

I've compiled vim with python3.5, so when **no virtualenv is activated I get**:

```
:py3 import sys; print(sys.executable)

/usr/bin/python3

:py3 import sys; print(sys.path)

[
    '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
    '/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '_vim_path_',
    '/home/<user>/.vim/bundle/vim-virtualenv/autoload'
    ]
```

After **activation of the virtualenv `venv` (python3.6), then opening vim, I get**:

```
:py3 import sys; print(sys.executable)

/home/<user>/.virtualenv/venv/bin/python3

:py3 import sys; print(sys.path)

[
    '/home/<user>/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
    '_vim_path_',
    '/home/<user>/.vim/bundle/vim-virtualenv/autoload'
    ]
```

Seems to work quite nicely so far.