# How do I configure the python location?

Tags: vimscript-python

The python I want to use is located at `C:\randomplace\python`.

I have a dev machine that has multiple instances of python (so relying on finding python in`$PATH` is unreliable).

How do I configure vim to use just the before mentioned for the purpose of vim plugins etc?

Comment: That seems to be a compile option, see [:h python](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html) and [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9488/15871). Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2999315/6164712

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
set pythonhome=C:\randomplace\python
set pythondll=C:\randomplace\python\python27.dll
```

For python3 use `pythonthreehome` and `pythonthreedll`.

For this to work python dynamic support must be compiled in. The following command must print `1`:

```
:echo has("python_dynamic")
```

For python3:

```
:echo has("python3_dynamic")
```

See `:help python-dynamic` and help for the named options.